# Flask app.teardown_appcontext not being called when DEBUG is false

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

**Problem:** 
Flask app.teardown_appcontext is not being called when DEBUG is false. Flask's app.teardown_request works just fine.

**Background:**
This problem was first discovered because of the error (2013, 'lost connection to mysql server during query') which was only happening when DEBUG = False

After looking into this further, I realized that this was because the session was not being removed properly in flask_sqlalchemy.

```
def create_app(config_obj):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    env = Environments(app)
    env.from_object(config_obj)

    # init extensions
    SetupLogs(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    api.init_app(app)
    CORS(app)

    # This gets called after each request
    @app.teardown_request
    def teardown_request(response_or_exc):
        db.session.remove()

    # This never gets called after requests only when DEBUG = False!
    @app.teardown_appcontext
    def teardown_appcontext(response_or_exc):
        db.session.remove()

    return app

app = create_app('config')
manager = Manager(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
...
```

Comment: I am not very sure and that is why I am not writing an answer but may be reading this - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#context-usage will help you. Just to quote - `"Generally there would be a get_X() function that creates resource X if it does not exist yet and otherwise returns the same resource, and a teardown_X() function that is registered as teardown handler."`

Comment: @SRC flask-sqlalchemy creates the scoped session at the start of the request, and is suppose to remove the session after each request. See details in [the road to enlightenment](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#road-to-enlightenment).  [Removing](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py#L76) does a little more than just closing the session

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the problem and it was actually a side effect of using Flask-Script with Flask-SqlAlchemy.

If SQLAlchemy is instantiated with init_app, then app.app_context().push() must be used if performing DB operations outside of the scoped session(made in the request). [More Details](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/contexts/) But if an app context is pushed, then it must be closed manually otherwise it will never be torn down and therefore never trigger the teardown_appcontext.

[Flask-Script runs commands inside a flask test context](https://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#accessing-local-proxies) which i believe kept the app context alive.